# write to android USB port and send it to a RS232 microbot port

Tags: java, android, usb, serial-port

I have an old android phone (2.2) and I need to use it to transfer a (.tok) file to Basic Stamp micro RS232 using a USB-Serial converter in between. So  bluetooth is out of question. My only option is to write to the USB port of my android and make the BS2 micro receive it.

I`ve never programmed Android so need some guidance as to how I do this, specially when my api level is 8. I need a simple program that reads a downloaded (from the processing local linux PC) file from sdcard and then send it to USB port without any processing. That file is then received by the RS232 port of bot.

Comment: +1 sounds like an interesting question :). You might need to do some bits in C, rather than java.

Comment: If you'll find solution in C (or C++) you can use JNI to call native function.

Comment: I have a native c++ solution for writing to the linux /dev/ttyS0 port and then send to RS232 port  .But not sure how to use it wrt android .

Comment: Why is Bluetooth out of the question?  It seems to be **exactly** what you are looking for.  I'd suggest grabbing a Bluetooth-to-RS232 converter and using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.2 API does not have USB host capabilities.

Host capabilities was not made available until Android 3.1.

This means you can't write an android program on your v2.2 phone that will control the USB communication.

I'm also guessing that even if you did update your OS, the phone doesn't have a USB-A port necessary to power the bus.

Comment: ls in /dev shows a list of virtual ports . like /tty/HUSB0 /tty/HUSB1 . I`m guessing that H is from the maker of the phone Huawei . and root is also possible . So I can just write to them for USB ,can`t I ?

Comment: Android 2.2 can be the accessory on USB. (e.g. your computer is the Host, and it reads data off of the phone).

But Android 2.2 cannot be the host.

I don't know anything about Huawei phones.

Answer (score 0):

no need "usb host", work an older android devices like 2.2 http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/

Comment: This would only work if the device actually has a hardware serial port, the user has appropriate cabling and voltage translation, the kernel on the device has a driver active, and the installed configuration will permit 3rd party apps to access the device node.  The last in particular is usually not the case on stock ROMs.